# vuei18n => translate array in setup() is making the <template/> translations to need an extra step/load to render, how can i solve it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, frontend, rendering

sorry for the "extra step/load" part, I know It's pretty vague and definitely a poor word choice. I will show you with what I mean with the code and 2 images.
1st:[image]

code:

```
<template>
  <div class="bg-white">
    <h1
      class="text-4xl font-semibold my-10 text-center capitalize text-black dark:text-white"
    >
      {{ t('FAQ.title') }}
    </h1>
    <div class="space-y-4 mx-auto my-4 max-w-screen-lg">
      <details class="group" v-for="faq in faqs" :key="faq.question">
        <summary
          class="flex items-center list-none text-left justify-between p-4 rounded-lg cursor-pointer"
        >
          <h5 class="font-medium text-black">{{ faq.question }}</h5>
          <svg
            class="flex-shrink-0 ml-1.5 w-5 h-5 transition duration-500 group-open:-rotate-180"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            fill="none"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            stroke="currentColor"
          >
            <path
              stroke-linecap="round"
              stroke-linejoin="round"
              stroke-width="2"
              d="M19 9l-7 7-7-7"
            />
          </svg>
        </summary>

        <ul v-if="faq.list">
          <li
            class="px-4 my-2 ml-4 leading-relaxed text-secondary"
            v-for="answer in faq.answer"
            :key="answer"
          >
            {{ answer }}
          </li>
        </ul>

        <p class="px-4 my-2 ml-4 leading-relaxed text-secondary" v-else>
          {{ faq.answer }}
        </p>
      </details>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'FAQ',
  setup() {
    const { t } = useI18n()
    const faqs = [
      {
        question: t('FAQ.questions[0]'),
        answer: t('FAQ.answers.answer1')
      },
      {
        question: t('FAQ.questions[1]'),
        answer: [
          t('FAQ.answers.answer2[0]'),
          t('FAQ.answers.answer2[1]'),
          t('FAQ.answers.answer2[2]'),
          t('FAQ.answers.answer2[3]'),
          t('FAQ.answers.answer2[4]')
        ],
        list: true
      },
      {
        question: t('FAQ.questions[2]'),
        answer: t('FAQ.answers.answer3')
      },
      {
        question: t('FAQ.questions[3]'),
        answer: t('FAQ.answers.answer4')
      },
      {
        question: t('FAQ.questions[4]'),
        answer: t('FAQ.answers.answer5')
      },
      {
        question: t('FAQ.questions[5]'),
        answer: t('FAQ.answers.answer6')
      },
      {
        question: t('FAQ.questions[6]'),
        answer: t('FAQ.answers.answer7')
      },
      {
        question: t('FAQ.questions[7]'),
        answer: t('FAQ.answers.answer8')
      },
      {
        question: t('FAQ.questions[8]'),
        answer: t('FAQ.answers.answer9')
      },
      {
        question: t('FAQ.questions[9]'),
        answer: t('FAQ.answers.answer10')
      },
      {
        question: t('FAQ.questions[10]'),
        answer: t('FAQ.answers.answer11')
      },
      {
        question: t('FAQ.questions[11]'),
        answer: t('FAQ.answers.answer12')
      }
    ]
    return { faqs, t }
  }
})
</script>
```

As you can see, the  is the only one with t() within the template.
The problem is that to render all the rest of the elements, I have to change the flag and go to another section of the page, and then come back, that's the extra step that i mean.
There's anyway I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

To make the rest of the questions and answers change along with the title, there are two ways you could fix it.

The first way would be to translate the questions and answers in the template like this:

```
{{ t(faq.question) }}
```

The second way would be to make `faqs` a computed property so that it would update whenever `t` changes.

Comment: If I make {{ t( faq.question) }} => I have to add the "" around faq.question and it renders as string, it doesnt work as key. And i will try the second one now! thanks